# Extending String between two stacked errors

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jestjs

```
class Name extends String {
     constructor(){
          super(...arguments);
     }
    valid(){
         return /[a-zA-Z]/.test(this);
    }

}
```

Using [expect of jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html) , I run my tests

```
const name=new Name('Ahmed'); // instruction does not throw exception 
it('something',()=>{
     expect(name.valid()).toEqual(true); //---calling valid make the ERROR
})
```

and i get the following error :

```
String.prototype.toString is not generic
```

So what i do , i implement `toString` as well as `valueOf` method manually .

```
class Name extends String {

    valid(){
         return /[a-zA-Z]/.test(this);
    }
    toString(){
         return this;
    }
    valueOf(){
         return this;
    }

}
```

I run again , i got :

```
: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

Comment: I have run first snippet and it works, no error.

Comment: it might be a pb of unit-test framework +jsx

Comment: Your question has a babel tag, which means that the resulting code is ES5. String is not subclassable in ES5. Your code works fine as is, i.e. as ES6 code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by implementing `toString` & `valueOf` as :

```
toString(){
  return Object.keys(this).map((k)=>this[k]).join('');
}
valueOf(){
  return Object.keys(this).map((k)=>this[k]).join('');
}
```

Because , when i inspect `new String('abc')` in console , i note that the result is `{0:'a',1:'b',2:'c'}`
And  :

```
 Object.keys({0:'a',1:'b',2:'c'}`).map((k)=>str[k]).join('') === 'abc'
```

#### However , i dare say it is strange to re-implement `toString` for children classes.

Comment: What ES5 code does this translate to? How efficient is this compared to using a class with a single string property? I don't understand the advantage of what you are doing.